# Change the Office 365 logo and link on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, office-365

I'd like to change the office 365 logo and link on my SharePoint 2013 so users don't leave the site, is this possible in SharePoint 2013?

I have managed to hide the logo and change background colours etc but i would prefer to use my own logo

[image: logo and link]

Answer (score 2):

You could use some lines of CSS to do that:

Remove the default

```
span .SHSpanLogo img{display:none;}
```

Add your logo:

```
.SHSpanLogo {background-mage:url(http://domain/SiteImages/logo.png)!important; background-color:transparent;background-position:top left;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:120px;}
```

Comment: how would we get round the a:link to office365.com?

Comment: I suggest to you to override it by javascript

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, managed to get it working using JS alone...although can't change the ALT and TITLE attributes..answer below

Answer (score 0):

Used the following JS

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ConfigureBrandingsuite");
```

function ConfigureBrandingsuite()
{
    // Replace the default logo with my Logo with transparant background 
    document.getElementById('suiteBrandingIcon').src = "/_catalogs/masterpage/xxxxxxxx/css/logoSml.png";
    document.getElementById('suiteBrandingIcon').alt = "My Alt tag";
    document.getElementById('suiteBrandingIcon').title = 'My Title';

```
// Setting the width to a little more than default, else the image may be cropped 
document.getElementById('suiteBrandingIcon').style.width = "120px";
document.getElementById('suiteBrandingIcon').style.height = "26px";

// Set the background of the entire suitebarleft - We are doing this in the CSS
// document.getElementById('suiteBarLeft').style.background = "#000000";

//Now we need to change the URL of the a:link
document.getElementById('suiteBrandingLink').href = "http://www.google.com/";
document.getElementById('suiteBrandingLink').title = "Go to Google";

}
```

The logo is being replaced but i cannot seem to change the ALT tag and the TITLE tag of the img using the above JS...also the office 365 logo briefly appears before my logo kicks in..

Cheers,

S